# How to create an Image slideShow , with just one Image ? (slides on itself)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, angularjs

Sorry for this confusing , broad , dummy like question.

Say I have just **ONE** Image , and I want to create an slide show , ( in angular or jquery or javascript or just with Css , whatever:().

All I want is when user click my slide button , this Image slides out to the right and while sliding to the right , simultaneously , this Image Slides in from the left ;

( The part of this image that has been silde out to the right , is comming in from the left , simultaneously)

Like this Illustration :

[image]

So actually this Imeage never disappears from view , just slides on itself.

I've created this with angularJS , but I cant make it simultaneous , I mean , The Image slides to the left , when done , it sileds in from the right , So there is moment that view is empty.
I dont want this

Please please Help me 
a Plugin , a css exapme , angular example , javascript ,jquery , anything will do .

Asking here is my last attempt , I've been searching and coding for a month , with no success:(

Comment: there are a zillion image carousels out there. granted indeed probably none will work with only one image i.e. one `<img src='pic.jpg />`. as you can see from your drawings, the one image called `pic.jpg` is actually present *twice* on your page. this means that you need need *two* instances of `<img src='pic.jpg />`. so, take any old plugin, and then set all of the elements' sources to `pic.jpg`.

Comment: why don't you just take one image and copy it.  That way you can slide between the two.  Use any of the sliders out there.

Comment: Actually, there is no Image
I want to make an slideShow on a Grid itself, 
When user clicks on next page of the grid ,
I want that the current page slides to right and new grid come in 
 like this : 
http://www.zocdoc.com/search/?address=&refine_search=Find+a+Doctor

Comment: Just have a look on the calendar of this page to see what I want :
http://www.zocdoc.com/search/?address=&refine_search=Find+a+Doctor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CSS can offer some possibilities.

One out many with a pseudo element, 
`text-indent` and `transition` and `pointer-events` to toggle the click effect.

`tabindex` in HTML to allow `div` to be focused via click and eventually via tab key.

**[DEMO](http://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/AHiue)**

HTML

```
<div class="slidebif" tabindex="0"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/300/people/9"/></div>
```

CSS

```
.slidebif {
  margin:1em auto;/* optionnal*/
  cursor:pointer;/* let's show it  clicks */
  width:200px;/* img width*/
  white-space:nowrap;/* keep img and cloned pseudo on same line */
  text-indent:0;/* set for transition */
  transition:0.5s;/* tune it */
  overflow:hidden;/* hide the pseudo */
}
.slidebif:after {
  content: url(http://lorempixel.com/200/300/people/9);/* same image as img src */
}
.slidebif:after, .slidebif img {
  vertical-align:top;/* optionnal*/
}
.slidebif:focus {
  text-indent:-200px;/* bring pseudo in sight */
  pointer-events:none;/* kill click catching , so it looses focus if clicked again */
}
```

---

**[variant with a 2 columns table](http://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/jLBvh)**.

Comment: This is exactly what I want 
But what if I dont want to slide on an Image
what If I replace the Image with a table ?
I mean like this : 
http://www.zocdoc.com/search/?address=&refine_search=Find+a+Doctor
click on calender to see what I mean 
please
thanks aloooooooot

Comment: if you want to use a  table, i guess you need to set all columns to same width. If it is to be more thna two columns, javaScript will be needed to make it bullet proff

Comment: @xe4me this can be made for a 2 col table or 2 col layout if elements are set as inline-block/inline-table. http://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/jLBvh

Comment: this is , The Exact , exact thing .

Thanks a lot
I'm looking into the code now
thanks

Comment: Why this doesn't work when tweeter bootstrap is on the page ?
I mean when I use boostrap , both two collumns will show side by side
and after click , both of them will slide ?

Comment: Why this doesn't work when tweeter bootstrap is on the page ? I mean when I use boostrap , both two collumns will show side by side and after click , both of them will slide ?

Comment: bootstrap overwrites the rules, can you set a fiddle or a codepen online with your code and CSS (linked to bootsrap) so we can see how to declare your rules over bootstrap rules.